# Chrome dev tools: Simulating different resolution PC screen

Tags: frontend, google-chrome-devtools, development-environment

I'm working with a QHD screen, and would like to simulate a FHD PC screen, not mobile device.

Currently in dev tools when I pick a device there are mobile phones/tablets and a "Responsive" option. The Responsive mode will also enable touch simulation and prevent mouse navigation via back/forward button.

Is there an option to simulate a different screen resolution without simulating a mobile device?

Comment: Click "Edit" in the device dropdown and add a custom device, choose "Desktop" type.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @wOxxOm You should add that as an answer. This helped me!